# How to install GRUB EFI to RAID1

Tags: raid, grub, efi

While configuring a new server, I try to install the Debian Linux Buster at mirrored disks /dev/sda and /dev/sdb with uEFI.
I tried various combination:

var1:

```
/dev/sda and /dev/sdb - > /dev/md1 (RAID1) with GPT partition table   
/dev/md1p1 - FAT32 partition 200MB EFI
/dev/md1p2 - ext4 partition 200GB    /
```

var2:

```
/dev/sda w. GPT, /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 raid member
/dev/sdb w. GPT, /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 raid member
/dev/sda1,  /dev/sdb1  - > /dev/md1 - FAT32 200MB EFI
/dev/sda2,  /dev/sdb2  - > /dev/md2 - ext4 200GB  /
```

but during Debian installation the GRUB refuses to be installed.

There is no option in GRUB installation step to force EFI installation. The only possibility is to finish the installation without a loader, and then do the GRUB/EFI manually.

But there are no hints, how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You may find your answer in the extremely detailed post
[Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with RAID 1 and LVM on machine with UEFI BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios).

The accepted answer is extremely long, so here are just the main points:

> 1. Download and boot into Ubuntu Live for 20.04.
> 2. Set up mdadm and lvm.
> 3. Run the Ubuntu installer, but do not reboot.
> 4. Add mdadm to target system.
> 5. Clone EFI partition to second drive.
> 6. Install second EFI partition into UEFI boot chain.
> 7. Reboot

Comment: Yes, you are right that it is an extremely long, and complex. I still didn't copy, if the LVM subsys is necessary. The main problems reamains: if I simply clone a system disk to make a mirrior (or making a mirror create a clone) there will be two partition with same LABEL, partuid, etc. what the modern systems do not like.